# lm.br - how do capture confidence interval on break point?

Tags: r, breakpoints

I am using lm.br to fit an "LL" (linear-linear) model.  I want to capture the confidence interval for the change point but have been unable to figure out how to do so.

Using the documentation example, we have:

> creatinine <- c(37.3,47.1,51.5,67.6,75.9,73.3,69.4,61.5,31.8,19.4)
>
> day <- 1:10
>
> sc <- lm.br(creatinine ~ day)
>
> sc

Which yields,

Call:
lm.br(formula = creatinine ~ day, type = "LL")

Changepoint and coefficients:

```
    theta         alpha   day < theta   day > theta 

  6.44115      82.52259       8.07143     -17.97000
```

Significance Level of H0:"no changepoint" vs H1:"one changepoint"

```
SL= 0.000163596  for theta0 = -0.5  by method CLR
```

95-percent confidence interval for changepoint 'theta' by CLR

```
[ 5.17344, 7.50078 ]
```

str(sc) reveals that ci is a function local to lm.br.  The output of that is:

> sc $ ci()

95-percent confidence interval for changepoint 'theta' by CLR
    [ 5.17344, 7.50078 ]

I've tried things like thisCI <- sc$ci(), as.numeric(sc$ci()), str(sc$ci()) and nothing seems to yield an object from which I can extract the CI limits.  I've tried looking at the lm.br source code, but it is beyond my (rudimentary) understanding of R.

There must be some way to extract these values so they can be used in other computations; I'd appreciate learning how.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation... "’lm.br’ returns a list that includes a C++ object with accessor functions". So, you have to capture the output as a string...

```
library("lm.br")
library("stringr")
creatinine <- c(37.3,47.1,51.5,67.6,75.9,73.3,69.4,61.5,31.8,19.4)
day <- 1:10
sc <- lm.br(creatinine ~ day)
ci <- capture.output(sc$ci())
> str_extract_all(ci[2], "\\b[0-9]*.[0-9]*\\b")[[1]]
[1] "5.17344" "7.50078"
```